# Reading file on remote server via Java

Tags: java, filereader, urlread

I am developing a Java application through which I need to read the log files present on a server and perform operations depending on the content of the logs.
Files range from 3GB up to 9GB.
Here on stack I have already read the discussion about reading large files with java, I am attaching the link:

[Java reading large file discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

In the discussion, the files are read locally,
in my case i have to retrieve and read the file on the server, is there an efficient way to achieve this?
I would like to avoid having to download files given their size.
I had thought about using URL Reader to retrieve the files, but I have doubts about the speed of execution.
The files I need to recover are under the path `C:\production\LOG\file.log`

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Assuming the machine running your Java application is also on Windows, why not map a network drive? Then you can read the remote file as if it were a local file.

Comment: @Abra, The machine on which the Java code is already a Mac and I communicate with the remote windows server via VPN..it is possible map a network in this case?